# PostgreSQL : Multiple PERFORM in a queue

Tags: postgresql

I have 30 functions in my database and I need to execute all one by one and they are all linked.

How can I say function x need to wait the execution of function x-1 to be launched ?

I have all PERFORM lines like this :

```
  PERFORM func1();
  PERFORM func2();
  PERFORM funcx();
  ....
```

And I want to 'inform' the func2 to wait until the func1() is done.

I can create a table with an increment and when each function is done, I update the value and add a while loop in my main function and when the value changed, a different function is executed.
It's an idea, not the ideal solution.

Regards

Comment: Put all calls into a single script and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

they are executed consequently, here is example:

```
so=# do $$
begin
perform pg_sleep(0.4);
raise info '%',clock_timestamp();
perform now();
raise info '%','2nd: '||clock_timestamp();
end; $$
;
INFO:  2017-10-31 20:13:03.105867+00
INFO:  2nd: 2017-10-31 20:13:03.106168+00
DO
Time: 402.273 ms
```

as you see second perform (which takes much less then 0.4 sec) waited first to complete...